# Javascript Operator with DOM event handler not working

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events, comparison-operators

I'm coding a game and when the game over appear, I want to be a specific text showing up according to the score.

Here's what I coded :

```
    <div id="game-over">
      <h3><font color="orange">Tu as courus <span id="score"></span> mètres, tu peux faire mieux (ou pas)</font></h3>
      <h1 id="customegotext" onmouseover="mouseOver()" onmouseout="mouseOut()">Passe ta souris içi</h1>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="button restart">Réessayer ?</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
      var scoretext;
    document.getElementById("score")
    if (score < 45) {
        scoretext = "Text1";
    } else if (score > 100 ) {
        scoretext = "Text2";
    } else if (score > 500 ) {
        scoretext = "Text3";
    } else if (score > 750 ) {
        scoretext = "Text4";
    } else {
        scoretext = "Text5";
    }
    document.getElementById("customegotext").innerHTML = scoretext;
function mouseOver() {
    document.getElementById("customegotext").style.color = "orange";
}

function mouseOut() {
    document.getElementById("customegotext").style.color = "black";
}
</script>
```

The problem is that it always show "text5".

PS: The "score" value is defined in a separate .js file.

Comment: Can you show the file where "score" is defined ? Or at least a sample of code from this file ?
First thing that comes to my mind is that "score" isn't modified properly

Comment: How are you populating the `score`? Looks like it is empty

Comment: In addition, you can add this line just before the `if .. else if...` block:  `console.info('score=', score);` then let us know what that printed.

Comment: I have a hunch that you think the line `document.getElementById("score")` is assigning the variable "score" the value of the element with id=score, but it's not doing such thing.

Comment: Probably you have to assign score like this before your if condition
score = document.getElementById("score");

Comment: The score is showing correctly in the game but I will show you the code to calculate the score

Comment: It's not about the score showing properly or not, it's about retrieving the score and using it for the game logic, what (I assume) everybody here is thinking is that your score variable is not set, so all of your conditionals are evaluating to false and the last option is reached.

Comment: can you try to print the "score" value in the above code

Comment: It print "score= <span id="score"></span>

Comment: Yes it's a DOM element, not a number. You have 2 correct answers by now. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You didn't set score anywhere.
Set it like this
 `var score = document.getElementById("score").innerHTML;`

Check it here https://jsfiddle.net/Luo87449/

Answer (score 1):

`score` is simply a **DOM object** (since id's by default become a global properties), here you need its value for comparison.

```
score = document.getElementById("score").innerHTML
```

Now it will have the value with which you can compare other `Numbers`.

Also, you need to do this invocation when there are values inside that `span`.

Code that you have posted above, is simply doing this comparison on page load when that `span` is empty.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your script code with below code:

```
<script>
    var scoretext;

    score = document.getElementById("score");

    if (score < 45) {
        scoretext = "Text1";
    } else if (score > 100 ) {
        scoretext = "Text2";
    } else if (score > 500 ) {
        scoretext = "Text3";
    } else if (score > 750 ) {
        scoretext = "Text4";
    } else {
        scoretext = "Text5";
    }

    document.getElementById("customegotext").innerHTML = scoretext;

    function mouseOver() {
        document.getElementById("customegotext").style.color = "orange";
    }

    function mouseOut() {
        document.getElementById("customegotext").style.color = "black";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: @k0spwn can you please alert(score); after score variable and show me the value

Comment: When when the game plays, the value that is showed is the current score, when the game over appear it shows nothing